# MongoDb - findOneAndDelete nested object query doesnt work

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query my db and I don't understand why it won't work I'm following the schema correctly but for what ever reason the findOneDelete one just deletes my whole container any help would be great!

```
            dbContainer.findOneAndDelete({
                "positions": {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        sampleID: request.params.sampleID
                    }
                }
            }).then((containerToUpdate) => {})
```

//my schema
boxID: String,
containerID: String,
status: Number,
boxType: Number,
containerType: Number,
comment:String,
positions: [{
position: Number,
vialID: String,
sampleID: String
}],

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of request.params.sampleID. in mongo sampleID: 1 and sampleID: '1' are considered different.

Can you try toString()

```
dbContainer.findOneAndDelete({
                "positions": {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        sampleID: request.params.sampleID.toString()
                    }
                }
            }).then((containerToUpdate) => {})
```

Comment: toString won't work cause the sampleID is a string and so is the request.params.sampleID, its very likely I have messed up some where else but I can't see how, thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

If the id its an ObjectId, you must do a parse. Mongoose offer this parse and you can just use as above:

```
dbContainer.findOneAndDelete({
            "positions": {
                $elemMatch: {
                    sampleID: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(request.params.sampleID)
                }
            }
        }).then((containerToUpdate) => {})
```

Comment: This unfortunately throws an error I have used this query on multiple other things but for some reason delete just doesn't like it!